# I want to create a tool that will search a single field, in a single layer and zoom to that location?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have a feature class of valves and another of fire hydrants. Each has a unique identifier field. I want to create a tool that has one dialogue that allows input of a identifier then zooms to that location. I have a solid understanding of coding and GIS. But don't even know where to start with this.

Any clues about where to start with this?

Comment: What version of Arcmap are you using?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

I did this using a [Python Add-In](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5f3aefe77f6b4f61ad3e4c62f30bff3b).

I used a combo box to get the user input and then did a search using `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management()` tool.  This is kind of a hack but it's the easiest way I've found to get input from a user in an easy to understand form.

Then it's just a matter of checking to see if there's only one thing selected - if yes, zoom to the selected thing, if not, well then do whatever you please - it doesn't sound like this will matter to you.

You'll have to modify the code below to provide for your layers but it's pretty straightforward.  Hopefully this will get you rolling.

Here's my code (which lives in the `onEnter()` event of the python file for the Addin:

```
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

    address_points = arcpy.mapping.Layer("County Address Points")

    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("County Address Points", "CLEAR_SELECTION")

    #Search is always conducted as a wildcard because there's too much variation in the addresses to be more specific.
    #This is case sensitive and doesn't account for things like Grant Road vs Grand Rd - when in doubt be less specific and look through more results
    #Full_Addy is the name of the field being searched and self.value is the text that the user input into the combo box.
    query = "UPPER(Full_Addy) LIKE " + "UPPER('%" + str(self.value) + "%')"
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(address_points,"NEW_SELECTION",query)
    print "Querying: " + query

    count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(address_points).getOutput(0))
    print str(count) + " Addresses Selected"

    if count == 1:
        df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
        if df.scale < 1200: 
            df.scale = 1200
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    elif count > 1:
        df.extent = address_points.getExtent()
        pythonaddins.MessageBox(str(count) + " Addresses Selected.\nSee Attribute Editor for Details", 'DE Lookup', 0)
    elif count == 0:
        pythonaddins.MessageBox("Search Returned No Results", 'DE Lookup Error', 0)`
```

Comment: Works in ArcMap 10.2.1